# How do i calculate how many employees fall into each category based on their scores SQL

Tags: sql, count, pivot, average

I have a table called respondent,within that table there is a column called 'score' i need to be able to divide the respondents by percentage based on their user score.

More specifically, what % of respondents fall below 22.5
What percent of respondents fall between 25.0 and 47.5
what percent of respondents fall between 50.0 and 75.0
what percent of respondents fall above 75.0

How would i express this in a QUERY, I need it group by respondent. Please i cant figure it out.

Comment: You can try using the **group by** command.

Comment: Do you know how that would look in a Query, how does the Query look, could you please show me ?

Comment: I would start by learning what RDBMS you are using. MySQL and SQL Server are 2 completely different RBDMS.

Comment: i am using MySQL, the Microsoft platform. Would you know how i can perform this query ? im in a very tight situation

Comment: Does it have to be in a single query? Are you allowed to use anything else?

Comment: Since you are new here take a minute and read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  If you follow the items outlined here you will have a better chance of getting valuable answers.  If this is for homework, read this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Any means, method or way to have this query displayed.

Comment: This is not for homework, its for a client.

Comment: *"i am using MySQL, the Microsoft platform."* Those statements are contradictory. MySQL is owned by Oracle, not Microsoft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation. The syntax varies across databases, but a rather portable way to express this is:

```
select
    avg(case when score < 22.5 then 1.0 else 0 end) ratio1,
    avg(case when score >= 25 and score < 47.5 then 1.0 else 0 end) ratio2,
    ...
from mytable
```

This gives the ratio as a decimal value between `0` and `1`, which you can multiply by `100` if you want a percentage.